# November 30 -0001 returned on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

Before anyone say's it, I checked other questions like this, but to no avail. Basically, I'm taking a timestamp from my DB and displaying it, here's the code for retrieval:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $timestamp = date("l F d Y", strtotime($row['timestamp']));
}
```

And here is the code for when it is submitted:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mysql_table (timestamp) VALUES (now())";
```

I thought it would be a simple formatting error (thus the strtotime) but that didn't work as you can see: http://aviatex14.co.uk/anonpost/index.php

I can change it to:

```
$date = date("l F d Y", $row['timestamp']);
```

and get December 31st 1969, but that's not heplful either..

Oh, my column data type is datetime.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: As @bumperbox notes, $row[timestamp] is probably incorrect-- my guess would be 0, since 31 Dec 1969 = the Unix epoch (west of UTC anyway)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put backticks around the word `timestamp` as this is a reserved word.

```
 "INSERT INTO mysql_table (`timestamp`) VALUES (now())";
```

Comment: You were right, var_dump returns: string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: you may have to put backticks around the word timestamp. i have amended answer as i can't get backticks to show in comments

Comment: Worked straight away. Thanks.

Comment: @LanceRoberts why did you edit out so much, it showed how the symptoms of were related to the solution

Comment: @bumperbox, because you were asking questions before (which should have been in a comment).  If you think some of it was relevant you're welcome to re-edit it, it just didn't seem that way to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going go to be doing the date formatting in PHP, then just fetch a UNIX_TIMESTAMP from MySQL, which is directly usable as a PHP timestamp:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) FROM  ...
```

Your `date(... $row['timestamp'])` fails because the date() function expects a TIME VALUE, which is just a unix time stamp - you're passing in the string representation of a date, which gets converted to `0`, most likely, which is Jan 1/1970 00:00, and then adjusted for timezones, so you get Dec 31/69 instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that php uses UNIX_TIMESTAMP, which does not match with MySQL's datetime format.

Either do

```
SELECT date_format(`timestamp`,aformatstring, see link) as formateddate_as_string
```

Or do

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) as php_friendly_timestamp
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format